# Type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory. Operator == not compatible with types string memory and string memory

Tags: solidity

I am new to Solidity and building a Todo List project.

I still got below error messages in the deductTask function even after using keccak256(abi.encodePacked())
to pack my string variables

**error 1 . Type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory.**

**error 2 . Operator == not compatible with types string memory and string memory**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract myTodoList {

    // Model a Task
    struct Task {
        uint id;
        string content;
        bool completed;
    }

    // Read/write Tasks
    mapping(uint => Task) public Tasks;
    
    // Store Tasks Count
    uint public TasksCount = 0;

    function addTask (string memory _content) public {
        TasksCount ++;
        Tasks[TasksCount] = Task(TasksCount, _content, false);
    }
    
    Task TaskTemp;
    
    function deductTask (string memory _contentClicked) public {
        string memory comparedContent;
        uint i ;
        for(i = 1; i <= TasksCount; i++) {
             TaskTemp = Tasks[i];
             comparedContent = TaskTemp.content;

             comparedContent = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(comparedContent));
             //comparedContent = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(comparedContent));
             _contentClicked = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_contentClicked));
             //_contentClicked = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_contentClicked));

             if(_contentClicked == comparedContent ){
                 delete Tasks[i];
              }
        }
        TasksCount --;   
    }

    
    constructor () public {
        addTask("my first task");
        addTask("my second task");
    }

}
```

Comment: The `keccak256()` hashing function returns a 32-byte array (`bytes32` Solidity datatype), not a string. In other programming languages, you can represent the byte array as 64 hex characters (a string). But there's no straightforward way to represent the byte array as a hex string in Solidity...  What is your intention when using the `addTask()` and `deductTask()`?  Does the `_content` in `addTask()` need to be the original string, or do you want it to be the hash?

Comment: I am using keccak256(abi.encodePacked()) because I was told it is a solution to my original problem, which I tried to compare 2 strings in a IF statement without hashed them, and I got error code No.2 above in the description..............but even after hashed those 2 strings I got the above No.1 and No.2 error code...